# Meaning and significance of "vaultlike door" and "contract around the object in a single yawn of appetite" in Egan's A Visit From The Goon Squad?

Tags: meaning

1. What is a vaultlike door? Is this a common adjective for a door?
2. What does yawn of appetite mean?

Would you please paraphrase/rephrase these sentences and explain their relevance?

From Chapter 1, "Found Objects", of Jennifer Egan's *A Visit From the Goon Squad* (emphasis added):

> It began the usual way, in the bathroom of the Lassimo Hotel. Sasha was adjusting her yellow eye shadow in the mirror when she noticed a bag on the floor beside the sink that must have belonged to the woman whose peeing she could faintly hear through **the vaultlike door of a toilet stall**. Inside the rim of the bag, barely visible, was a wallet made of pale green leather. It was easy for Sasha to recognize, looking back, that the peeing woman's blind trust had provoked her: We live in a city where people will steal the hair off your head if you give them half a chance, but you leave your stuff lying in plain sight and expect it to be waiting for you when you come back? It made her want to teach the woman a lesson. But this wish only camouflaged the deeper feeling Sasha always had: that at, tender wallet, offering itself to her hand-it seemed so dull, so life-as-usual to just leave it there rather than seize the moment, accept the challenge, take the leap, fly the coop, throw caution to the wind, live dangerously ("I get it," Coz, her therapist, said), and take the fucking thing.
>
> [...]
>
> Sasha sighed. She'd told Coz the plumber story about a month ago, and he'd found a way to bring it up at almost every session since. The plumber was an old man, sent by Sasha's landlord to investigate a leak in the apartment below hers. He'd appeared in Sasha's doorway, tufts of gray on his head, and within a minute-boom-he'd hit the floor and crawled under her bathtub like an animal fumbling its way into a familiar hole. The fingers he'd groped toward the bolts behind the tub were grimed to cigar stubs, and reaching made his sweatshirt hike up, exposing a soft white back. Sasha turned away, stricken by the old man's abasement, anxious to leave for her temp job, except that the plumber was talking to her, asking about the length and frequency of her showers. "I never use it," she told him curtly. "I shower at the gym." He nodded without acknowledging her rudeness, apparently used to it. Sasha's nose began to prickle; she shut her eyes and pushed hard on both temples.
>
> Opening her eyes, she saw the plumber's tool belt lying on the floor at her feet. It had a beautiful screwdriver in it, the orange translucent handle gleaming like a lollipop in its worn leather loop, the silvery shaft sculpted, sparkling. **Sasha felt herself contract around the object in a single yawn of appetite**; she needed to hold the screwdriver, just for a minute. She bent her knees and plucked it noiselessly from the belt

Comment: A "vault-like" door is like the door of a bank vault i.e. thick and heavy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_vault#/media/File:WinonaSavingsBankVault.JPG

Answer (score 3):

A *vaultlike door* is a door that has some of the attributes of a vault. It's not that common, but its meaning is clear. This door is presumably vaultlike because it's very heavy (unlike most stall doors in bathrooms), as the sound of peeing only faintly comes through it.

*A yawn of appetite* is a metaphor whose exact meaning is less clear. Presumably, it's *appetite* because she really wants the screwdriver, and *yawn* because it's completely encompassed by her attention.